# Converting a byte array into an image

Tags: asp.net

I keep on getting a GDI+ error whenever I tempt to save an Image in a specified string path..
This is the code:
Can you advise please?

```
        System.Drawing.Image newImage;
        byte[] b= (byte[])Session["Image"];
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(b))
        {
            newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream); 
            newImage.Save("C:\\test.png"); //this is where the GDI+ error is thrown
            Image1.Attributes.Add("src", "C:\\test");

        }
```

Comment: What is the error? Does the user the server is running as have access to write to `C:\`?

Comment: Error says that `Session["Image"]` contains invalid data. Show us code that bind (array of bytes -- Image) data to `Session`.

Comment: Chart1.SaveImage(m, ChartImageFormat.Png); // where m is a memorystream variable 
Session.Add("Image", m.ToArray());

Comment: User is authorized to write to C...

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to convert the bytes to an image, and then convert the image to bytes again?

Otherwise you can just save the bytes directly:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("C:\\test.png", (byte[])Session["Image"]);
```